# Content.Date in AutoroutePart Patterns are not working as expected

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am having trouble with the {Content.Date.Year} token not working in AutoroutePart pattern. If I use just the {Content.Date}, the URL is create with a URL that looks like this:

```
events/5/25/2014 3:28:26 AM/my-event-page
```

If I use Content.Date.Year, it only returns null and the URL has two "//" instead of a year value:

```
events//my-event-page
```

Patterns are like this:

```
events/{Content.Date}/{Content.Slug}
events/{Content.Date.Year}/{Content.Slug}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you read that `{Content.Date.Year}` would work. The Date token has no year token that I can see in the source. Use `{Content.Date.Format:yyyy}` instead.

Comment: Thank you, Bertrand. You are so prolific and helpful, I'm sure I'll be asking your help again one day. But, to answer your question, I read it on your blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/07/27/future-orchard-part-2-more-tokens.aspx

Comment: ...but I see now I should have read your post more thoroughly.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Doh! Yes, that was an example that was written before the feature implementation was completed, and those tokens were never implemented.